# Why is my PHP file replaced with old code?

Tags: php, html, atom-editor

I have been using Atom for sometime now. A week ago, I was working on a website project, and coded my index.php page. Half way into the project, I noticed some missing changes on the code and had to rewrite the code which has some about paragraph text in it.
Two days later, when I opened the same project, I notice that the eelier changes I had made to the index.php, which I thought were lost somehow were now present in my project, with the rewrite having a few code line, mixed with initial lost code. I thought this could be just my confusion and I continued with my project rewriting it.
Now the problem is I finished the index.php header and footer php, and now realize that some changes are now missing and again replaced with some old code and paragraph text. Have anybody meet such a scenario, and how did he/she mitigate it. I'm pretty sure this has nothing to do with unsaved changes because we always save to refresh as see how the page is coming up.

Comment: Are you using a version control system?

Comment: No I am not, though it comes built into Atom,

Comment: I asked because this seems like a version control problem, where you reverted to a previous version.